# SSIS XML Configuration in SQL Server

Tags: ssis

After creating .dtsConfig file using Package Configurations, I want to assign connection string value in XML file to the package level variable using expression.

Can anyone tell me what is the expression to get the conn string value from XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stored the connection string in a XML config file you should have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTSConfiguration>
<DTSConfigurationHeading>
    <DTSConfigurationFileInfo GeneratedBy="user.name" GeneratedFromPackageName="your package" GeneratedFromPackageID="{DCA17C6E-F7BD-4084-8DCA-69806C89FB71}" GeneratedDate="4/10/2014 1:18:15 PM"/>
</DTSConfigurationHeading>
<Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[AW].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue>Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2012;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;</ConfiguredValue>
</Configuration>
</DTSConfiguration>
```

If you created the file using the package configuration wizard, you don´t need to assigned the value of the connection string using a expression. It is assigned automatically when you open the package.

Other way to configure your connection string is creating a variable with Data type String. In the Package Configurations store the value of the variable in the config file. Then you can map the variables to the connection string property of the connection using the Expressions attribute in the properties windows. Everything depens on what you really want to do.

If you have any questions just ask again.

Kind Regards,
Paul